# Why can't play music from downloads path using Mediaplayer?

Tags: java, android

*I copied the source code of the mp3 player from the URL from Github and it works but when I change URL to the downloads path. the music does not play. please how to solve this problem. I've tried many ways but does not work.*

**musicplayer.java**

```
      prepareMediaPlayer();

        ImageView forwardbutton = findViewById(R.id.forward);
        forwardbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    }
                }


            }
        });

        ImageView rewindbutton = findViewById(R.id.backword);
        rewindbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        imagePlaypause = findViewById(R.id.play);
        textCurrentTime = findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        playerSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);


        ImageView imgvs = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);


        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

        Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("image")).into(imgvs);

        TextView artistname = findViewById(R.id.ArtistName);
        TextView songname = findViewById(R.id.SongName);
        artistname.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("artist"));
        songname.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));


        ImageView closebutton = findViewById(R.id.closebutton);

        closebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mediaPlayer.pause();
                handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                finish();


            }
        });

        imagePlaypause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediaplay);


                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediapause);
                    updateSeekBar();

                }
            }
        });

        textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));


        playerSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                int playPosition = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return false;
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                playerSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(i);
            }
        });


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                playerSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.mediaplay);
                textCurrentTime.setText(R.string.zero);
                textTotalDuration.setText((R.string.zero));
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        }
    };


    private void prepareMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator +
                    "SNOR - HKAYA.mp3");
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

        } catch (Exception exception) {


        }
    }

    private void updateSeekBar() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            playerSeekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(updater, 1000);
        }


    }


    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds) {
        String timerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";

        int hours = (int) (milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int) (milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

        if (hours > 0) {
            timerString = hours + "";
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }

        timerString = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
        return timerString;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        StartAppAd.onBackPressed(this);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
        finish();

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

*I copied the source code of the mp3 player from the URL from Github and it works but when I change URL to the downloads path. the music does not play. please how to solve this problem. I've tried many ways but does not work.*

Comment: Why did you post all that irrelevant code? Please remove it. Post only problematic code.

Comment: @blackapps I know but I don't know what to post in order to get answers. one thing I do is just to copy/paste my code

Comment: Only the code where you try to start the file. Thats all